# IE8 does not hover when using an li with position:absolute

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8, hover

I have a sort of an image map, where I've used li's to create the elements, and on hovering the information pops up. The html code is:

```
<li id="b906" style="z-index: 1000;">
    <a href="#">
        <span>&nbsp;</span>
        <span class="para">Some text and maybe an image goes here.</span>
    </a>
</li>
```

And the CSS code for the corresponding HTML is:

```
#map ul li {
position: absolute;
list-style: none;
top: 0;
left: 0;
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
text-align: center;
display: block;
}

#map ul li a {
color: #000;
text-decoration: none;
color: #fff;
display: none;
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
}

#map ul li:hover a {
display: block;
}

#map ul li a span {
display: block;
width: 100%;
height: 120px;
border: 2px solid #777;
}

#map ul li a span.para {
display: block;
background: #777;
padding: 2px;
-moz-border-radius: 5px;
border-radius: 5px;
width: 100px;
}
```

This works splendidly in all the browsers, but IE8 does not show the spans on hover. However, if I put a border: 1px solid red; on the li, the spans do show up, but only if my mouse is exactly on that 1px thin border. Doesn't show up still if the cursor is *inside* the li.

What am I doing wrong here? :(
Thanks for the help.

Comment: Can we see more of your HTML document to help determine which document mode IE8 is using? Also, `<span class="para">` looks like a paragraph to me... why not just use `<p>`?

Comment: *(reference)* [CSS Compatibility and Internet Explorer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc351024%28VS.85%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Internet Explorer has some problems with dealing with :hover events, especially for li elements. You need to use this: http://www.xs4all.nl/~peterned/csshover.html

Should work for you then.
If all else fails, and in my case, I use jQuery's hoverIntent to show menus reliably.

Answer (score 0):

From http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms530766.aspx

> Windows Internet Explorer 7 and later, in standards-compliant mode (strict !DOCTYPE), can apply the :hover pseudo-class to any element, not only links. If the pseudo-class is not applied specifically to an element in the selector, such as the A tag, the Universal (*) Selector is assumed. Indiscriminate use of the :hover pseudo-class can negatively impact page performance.

See [Defining Document Compatibility](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc288325.aspx)