# CSS dropdown menu not showing in IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer, dropdownbox

I just discovered that the CSS dropdown menus on this site do not work in Internet Explorer. Not at all, absolutely nothing shows.
The menus work just fine in Firefox, and in Android
Here is the site:  http://anlea.org
I've tried a number of fixes, but nothing makes the dropdown menus show up.

Any (simple!) solutions would be greatly appreciated

Comment: I'm not seeing any errors but the W3C validator see 340 of them: http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fanlea.org%2F&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0

Comment: what version and modus of IE?

Answer (score 0):

IE doesn't always play nice with `li:hover` which is what your CSS menu appears to be relying on. The accepted answer to this question may be of help: [IE8 does not hover when using an li with position:absolute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3296155/ie8-does-not-hover-when-using-an-li-with-positionabsolute)

Comment: The solution proposed on your linked page above IE8 does not hover.... works.
I added the body tag { behavior: url("csshover3.htc"); } and your csshover.htc file, and it now works. Took 2 minutes.

Only problem the menu items are now about 80 px to the right of the main menu blocks. But that's a minor issue, the main thing it that your solution works.  THANKS

Answer (score 0):

You are not displaying the nested ul on hover, just the li's inside the nested ul. Try adding this:

```
.main_menu > ul > li:hover > ul {
   display: block;
}
```

also i would advise you to work with child selectors so something like this:

```
.main_menu ul li  /* this would also apply to the submenu's, you overwrite them later in your code */
```

would become

```
.main_menu > ul > li  /* this will only apply to the top level menu */
```

for nested menu's. This should not brake the code, but will keep you much more in control and avoid unexpected results.

if you want all li to have the same background for example, both top level and nested, you could still use

```
.main_menu li
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using IE9 to view the site and the menu works fine, only after I switch back to IE9 Standard Mode.

Your site defaults to the Quirks Mode in IE9.

You can refer to here: http://blog.timolthof.com/disable-quirks-mode/ to try to disable Quirks Mode.

Comment: In fact, this is a very simple way of solving the problem.
Just diasble quirks mode, as indicated in timolthof's blog

Comment: This is the simplest solution

Answer (score 0):

height and width of the drop down should be given in px not in % some versions IE does not support width and height in %