# Strange behavior on li positioned relative with submenu

Tags: css, wordpress, menu

In IE9 or less the submenus will not appear. The border of the submenus appears, but the background and the li doesn't.

You can find the issue [here](http://www.friedmandentalgroup.com/).

Comment: HTML & CSS please. A link is not adequate.

Comment: @Paulie_D I think the link is enough here :/

Comment: Then I suggest you re-read the guidance on posting questions. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: In this case I don't think that it would be useful to just paste all the css here. It is more helpful to see the issue and resolve it in it's actual context.

Comment: Its kinda part of the guidelines `[..]But if your problem is with code you've written, you should include some. But don't just copy in your entire program!`

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing any code, I would suggest that this is something to do with IEs interpretation of the :hover pseudo-class.

Also you should set the parent element of the sub menu to position: relative;

Check out this question;
[IE8 does not hover when using an li with position:absolute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3296155/ie8-does-not-hover-when-using-an-li-with-positionabsolute)